# Can I train a new vec into an existing opencv model

Tags: opencv, object-detection

I had used opencv_traincascade to train an object, say, using a.vec.
Later, I found some additional images as possitive samples and negative samples. So I build new samples, say, b.vec.

Can I run opencv_traincascade again using b.vec to refine the existing model? Or should I build a new vec including new and old images, and train a completely new model?

Thanks very much.